# Is there a word for a person who officially "takes over" for someone after they die?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example I want to write "Professor Dattani died, but I am going to ask his wife Virginia Dattani, who is acting as his _____, to forward you his confidential letter of reference that he wrote for me before before he died".

Comment: The official word for a person who administers another's will is "executor". But I would see no reason why it should not be used more loosely, and is probably the word I would use here. Or you could call them "the deceased's representative", or simply "representative".

Comment: That's very helpful. Why not write an answer so that I can upvote?  don't like the word "executor" especially in this sentence, but I might use "deceased's representative" if no one else answers. That is VERY helpful, thank you.

Comment: Executioner and executor as suggested by @WS2 are different words

Comment: It's **not** _executioner_. You can use _executor_, but that's a legal term and should apply only to legal matters; undoubtedly Pr. Neville has an executor (anyone who's just died has one), but you can use different version -- there are literary executors for writers and academic executors for academics, to take care of the non-legal aspects of the unfinished work.

Comment: Not sure what sense you seek, here. An executor is chosen to enact someone's specific will. An heir takes over the duties and responsibilities. Successors are the people select to replace those no longer available in a specific role. Which of these are the sort of term you're looking for?

Comment: @JohnLawler No, not anyone who's just died has an executor.

Comment: @TheNate An heir has no duties or responsibilities.

Comment: @michael.hor257k The heck you say. There are legal and moral responsibilities associated to any property.

Comment: @TheNate Indeed I do. Legal duties cannot be foisted on someone by the death of another person. Moral responsibilities are irrelevant to the question, I think.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Rejecting the inheritance is the only way out of inheriting any legal responsibilities from a property transfer. You inherit a controlling interest in a corporation, you also inherit a legal responsibility to the shareholders and staff. You inherit a building, any responsibility to maintain the grounds/safety comes with. This is pretty normal. If nothing else, inheriting cash comes with taxes.

Comment: @TheNate You are confusing duties that arise from ownership with duties that arise from inheritance. Duties that arise from ownership apply regardless of *how* the owner acquired the property. There are no duties arising from inheritance. Otherwise I would be happy to bequeath you my debts.

Comment: @michael.hor257k That's some tortured logic; I'm out

Comment: @JohnLawler I would agree that "executor" is a legal term, and is probably best avoided in the OP's context. "Deceased's representative" is the term they would be looking for here. Please be aware that I did not suggest "executioner" as erroneously reported.

Comment: @WS2: I am extremely sorry for making that mistake, I'd been working 18 hours straight, missed a midnight deadline and kept working until submitting the report at 9am. I did not have ill intent when editing my question.

Comment: @user1271772 I wasn't offended. But as one who has "executed" a will, I stress I did so as an "executor" - not "executioner"!

Answer (score 5):

The exact title of the person who *officially* “takes over” for someone after they die depends on how they become responsible for this task:

- If the deceased has left a will and named a person to act on behalf of the estate, then this person is the ***[executor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executor)*** ;
- if the deceased has died intestate, and a person has been appointed by court to administer the estate, then this person is the ***[administrator of the estate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrator_of_an_estate)***.

A common term that may be used for both types is ***[legal personal representative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_representative)*** - however, there are also other types of personal representatives, e.g. a legal guardian.

---

Note that this may vary by jurisdiction. These terms are generally used in [common law jurisdictions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_law#In_jurisdictions_around_the_world).

---

With all that said, I don't think you *need* the official title - at least not in the given example, where in most likelihood you would not even know what that title is, nor would the recipient care. You could simply write:

> Professor Neville died, but I am going to ask his widow Virginia
>   Neville to forward you his confidential letter of reference that he
>   wrote for me before he died.

Answer (score 1):

Conservator is also used in some legal jurisdictions for a person who oversees a person's will both before death, and after.